# how to use GUI to create directory

Tags: gui

how to create a directory on the desktop using GUI
and how to create an empty txt file in the directory using GUIand how to write my name in the text and save it using VI
and how to delete all of this using gedit

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! ;-) We're sorry but Ask Ubuntu is not a forum but a Question&Answer site: It works best if you ask one question, so you can receive one answer.  When you ask multiple questions, you need to find one expert versed in multiple areas which becomes more unlikely the more questions you put into... well, one question!  ;-) So please, split up your question into multiple questions and drop me a comment so I can answer one of your questions.

Answer (score 6):

The same way as in Windows, more or less. From the Files file browser:

- To make a directory -- right-click and select *New Folder*.
- To make a file -- right-click and select *New Document* -> *Empty Document*.
- To edit the new file -- right-click the new file and *Open With* -> *Other Application* -> *GVim* (GVim is vi with a better GUI. GVim is in the Ubuntu repos.).
- To delete all of the above -- the easy to delete anything is to click it once and send it to the Trash by pressing the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key. Sorry, no Gedit. Alright, if you must do it that way, open Gedit and from the Gedit menu select *Edit* -> *Preferences* -> *Plugins* tab -> put a check mark to the left of *External Tools*. Restart Gedit, and now you can run commands in Gedit by selecting *Tools* -> *External Tools* -> *Run command*. What's the point though? You can only run commands the same way as you would run them in the terminal, so you lose the advantage of using a GUI program.

Comment: And if your list of files is full and there is no space in the window and you can't right click, then you can click the options at the top with the 3 horizontal lines to add a folder.

Answer (score 4):

There is a trick.
Under Windows, if your files are in list or detail view, the right click always gives you the option New File, New folder.
Under Ubuntu, if the directory is in List view, every place you click a file or folder is selected and Ubuntu only shows the options for manipulation for the highlighted file.
You have to click the small icon view, then all objects are clustered and there is free space. You have to click the free space with no single file or folder highlighted. It's trivial, but not for a (linux) novice like me or (probably) Amr Saad. Cheers.

Comment: This depends on the used DE and its file manager, but I think it is true for Unity with Nautilus and XFCE with Thunar. You can also look in the menu (gear symbol in Nautilus, "File" menu in Thunar) for entries like "New folder...", "New file..."

Comment: true for gnome - this is crazy sad that the UI is so poor in 2020 :(